# Using fs to convert a file to base64, not stable

Tags: file, base64

I can't get base64 string from a file. I tried the below and it worked for only two times and stopped. What I mean is, the Client received the sent data fully and not as null only twice after many trials. Then, after that, it didn't work again.

```
filePath = `${__dirname}${filePath}`;
        filePath = filePath.replace(/\\/g, '/');
        const buf = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'base64'});
        const bufB = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
        const b64 = buf.toString('base64');
        console.log('BUFFER/A', buf);
        console.log('BUFFER/B', bufB);
        console.log('B64', b64);
        getRes.status(200).send(b64)
```

From the console, only bufB is a buffer, while both buf and b64 returned null.
I then tested it by supplying the base64 from the below

```
var testString = 'Sample text';
const getBuffer = new Buffer(testString);
const getBase64 = getBuffer.toString('base64');
getRes.status(200).send(getBase64);
```

Using the second code returned data that was used to recreate the file on the client, and the downloaded file size was as expected, unlike the first code which only gave zero kb.

See the screenshot of the Client and console:

[image]

I have searched for a solution to this, but none yet. How do I achieve this, please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.

The code is correct and have been working fine since. I somehow checked the source file in the node project whose data is been sent to the Client, is actually zero kb in size. I don't know at what point the original file was overwritten. I replaced it. Now, it is working fine.

See for your self. From the console, only bufB is a buffer, while both buf and b64 returned the expected base64. The file downloaded is of same size as the source file.

[image]

Thank you Guys.